# Filebeat > Logstash > ElasticSearch - Lumberjack Error

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

Trying to get Filebeat to work with logstash. Currently I am getting this error:

```
2016/11/14 04:54:27.721478 output.go:109: DBG  output worker: publish 2047 events
2016/11/14 04:54:27.756650 sync.go:85: ERR Failed to publish events caused by: lumberjack protocol error
2016/11/14 04:54:27.756676 single.go:91: INFO Error publishing events (retrying): lumberjack protocol error
2016/11/14 04:54:28.782729 sync.go:85: ERR Failed to publish events caused by: lumberjack protocol error
2016/11/14 04:54:28.782756 single.go:91: INFO Error publishing events (retrying): lumberjack protocol error
2016/11/14 04:54:30.786983 sync.go:85: ERR Failed to publish events caused by: lumberjack protocol error
2016/11/14 04:54:30.787017 single.go:91: INFO Error publishing events (retrying): lumberjack protocol error
2016/11/14 04:54:34.808528 sync.go:85: ERR Failed to publish events caused by: lumberjack protocol error
2016/11/14 04:54:34.808578 single.go:91: INFO Error publishing events (retrying): lumberjack protocol error
```

Does anyone have a solution or perhaps you can point me in the right direction?

Filebeat v5 and logstash v5.

doing this locally.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your filebeat and logstash configurations? Do you have any kind of authentication set up between the two?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It could be because your logstash is not visible to your filebeat.
Please start your logstash on beat as input. I have started my logstash on port no 31311.

```
    input {
  beats {
    host => "0.0.0.0"
    port => 31311
  }
}
```

Configuration in filebeat.yml : ElasaticSearch output is by default. Please comment it and uncomment logstash output configuration. It should look like as below.

```
output.logstash:
  # The Logstash hosts
  hosts: ["localhost:31311"]
```

Please take care if you have any authentication set up between these two.
I am able to see my messages into logstash and finally in Kibana after doing this configuration. Hope it will work.

Comment: Hey guys thanks for the answers! I got it to work. It was an incorrect host and port.

Comment: I want to ask that how to open this logstash port ? Where in the logstash.yml file, the port is specified ?